# Grammatical functions of "both"

Tags: adverbs

Consider the following sentences:

> My parents are both teachers.

> Sarah and Jane have both applied for the job.

I looked up "both" in some dictionaries, and none of them defines it as an adverb. Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, but you can also put _both_ at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: "Both" belongs to the word class (part of speech) determinative.

Comment: @BillJ would you explain more? Because, I thought determinatives have to come before a noun. For example: "Both cars are good." But here "both" isn't before a noun. Another question is that, which category of determinatives does "both" belong to? I mean, Articles, Demonstrative determiners, Interrogative determiners, Possessive determiners, Quantifiers, Numerals, Noun phrases?

Comment: It is separable and not part of the subject NP, but an adjunct in clause structure.This is evident from the fact that when the verb is an auxiliary "both" preferentially follows rather then precedes it. Compare _Sarah and Jane have both applied for the job_ ~ _Sarah and Jane both have applied for the job_.  "Both" belongs to the category 'universal determinative'.

Comment: @BillJ I googled "Universal Determinative" but didn't find anything. Can you explain it? Also you mentioned that "both" is an Adjunct, and it is confusing to me, because I read that Adjunct is a subcategory of Adverbials. Is it possible for a word in one instance to be both Determinative and Adverbial? Or maybe it is too advance for me, cause my grammar level is lower-intermediate.

Comment: You can call it a quantificational determinative. An adjunct is generally a modifier in clause structure where it modifies the verb or verb phrase. Sometimes, though, it is a supplement (a parenthetical), not a modifier. Some people call adjuncts adverbials. Determinative is a word category, not a function, so yes a determinative can function as an adjunct, as it does in your examples. – BillJ 3 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of those sentences are correct.
I wouldn't overthink the usage of "both", just use it when you want to talk about two of something.
"Both of my cats are black."
"My cats are both black."

Answer (score 0):

> > My parents are *both* teachers.
>
> > Sarah and Jane have *both* applied for the job.
>
> I looked up "both" in some dictionaries, and none of them defines it
> as an **adverb**.

1. In the given sentences, the word 'both' is modifying the nouns 'parents', 'Sarah' and 'Jane', so is not an adverb, but a **determiner**. Alternative phrasings with 'both' performing the same function:

   - *Both* my parents are teachers
   - *Both* Sarah and Jane have applied for the job.
2. In contrast, in this sentence, the word 'both' is an **adverb**:

   - Sarah and Jane have *both* applied for the job and gotten it.

> I thought determinatives have to come before a noun.

Not necessarily; however, [these phrasings are probably ungrammatical](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613373/484417):

- My parents *both* are teachers
- Sarah and Jane *both* have applied for the job.